# sending data from iphone into database over the network securily

Tags: iphone, database

I have mysql database i.e. central database and i use  ASP .net.

I want to send data from iPhone i.e. user information like name, city etc. over the network into the database. How can i do that. Please suggest. The connection should be secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , it's Possible , Create your ASP.NET web service to store data in database received from iPhone , for Secure purpose try with SSL Support , https://yourservice.com/iphonedata - POST Method parameters.

And also if it contains authentication service to use your web service ,use NSURLCOnnection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge.

Hope this could a Start!